# Oracle/MYSQL: Sort records from a select query on a column that contains alphanumeric values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sorting

I know that this question has been asked in various forms but my requirement happens to be a bit different.

Suppose I have a table that contains data as follows:

```
ID  NAME        VALUE

-----------------------------

1   ABC-2-2     X
2   PQRS-1-3    Y
3   ABC-3-2     Z
4   PQRS-1-4    A
5   PQRS-3-4    B
6   MNO-2-1     C
7   AAA-1       D
8   BBB-2       E
9   CCC-3       F
```

Now, the output that I'm expecting should look something like this:

```
ID  NAME        VALUE

-----------------------------
7   AAA-1       D
2   PQRS-1-3    Y
4   PQRS-1-4    A
8   BBB-2       E
6   MNO-2-1     C
1   ABC-2-2     X
9   CCC-3       F
3   ABC-3-2     Z
5   PQRS-3-4    B
```

Note that this is not a direct alpha-numeric sort.  Instead, the value before the first "-" is ignored and the fields are sorted on what is after the first "-" in the name.

I'm not very familiar with PL/SQL and any kind of help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

PS: Note that this should work on both Oracle and MySQL.

Comment: PL/SQL is *only* used for stored procedure in Oracle. Regular queries are simply "SQL". I doubt there will be a statement that will work on both DBMS. The functions to do something like this are just to different (e.g. in Oracle it should be easy with a regexp_replace, which MySQL doesn't have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example this would suffice (Oracle syntax):

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(name,4)
```

If the number of characters before the first hyphen can vary, you can do this (again Oracle syntax):

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'-')+1)
```

However that won't work if you have codes like:

```
AAA-10-1
AAA-8-1
AAA-9-1
```

and expect `AAA-10-1` to appear after `AAA-9-1`.  Then you will need to parse it further:

```
ORDER BY LPAD(SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'-')+1, INSTR(name,'-',1,2)-INSTR(name,'-')-1),10,'0'),
         LPAD(SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'-',1,2)+1),10,'0')
```

(NB I have used LPAD(x,10,'0') to turn a value like '1' into '0000000001' and so on, rather than use TO_NUMBER since this could fail if there are any non-numerics in your data.)

Example:

```
with data as
(
select 'AAA-1' name from dual
union all
select 'PQR-1-4' name from dual
union all
select 'PQR-1-3' name from dual
union all
select 'AAA-10-10' name from dual
union all
select 'AAA-10-1' name from dual
union all
select 'AAA-9-10' name from dual
union all
select 'AAA-9-1' name from dual
)
select *
from data
ORDER BY LPAD(SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'-')+1, INSTR(name,'-',1,2)-INSTR(name,'-')-1),10,'0'),
         LPAD(SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'-',1,2)+1),10,'0');
```

Output:

```
NAME
---------
PQR-1-3
PQR-1-4
AAA-9-1
AAA-9-10
AAA-10-1
AAA-10-10
AAA-1
```

And if AAA-1 should come first:

```
ORDER BY LPAD(SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'-')+1, INSTR(name||'-','-',1,2)-INSTR(name,'-')-1),10,'0'),
         LPAD(SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name||'-','-',1,2)+1),10,'0') nulls first
```

Comment: Great. Thanks!  What if AAA-1 has to come before AAA-9-1?
OK... I'll try to figure it out myself... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about mysql syntax, but you can do this in oracle:

```
select * from  <your_table>
order by substr(name, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

in mssql the syntax of finding your problem is :

```
select * from mytable order by substring(name,PATINDEX('%-%',name)+1,len(name)-PATINDEX('%-%',name))
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8bba/20)